# What rep limits are there in addition to the daily rep cap mentioned in the FAQ?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

The FAQ states that the daily rep cap is **200**.

However...

[image: I’m already capped at 180?]

Any idea what’s going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you deleted one of your answers that had already received two upvotes. Deleted upvotes are still counted against the reputation limit (at least until your reputation is recalculated).

Comment: Hang on, you’re implying that deleting an answer with 2 upvotes subtracts 20 rep but also reduces the daily limit to 180 for me?

Comment: @Timwi: It doesn't subtract the 20 rep (until the next recalc, that is), it just doesn't show it in your reputation activity.

Comment: Ah, I see. So to clarify: At the next recalc, the rep from the deleted answer no longer counts, but the upvotes from all the other answers will give me 200, right?

Comment: @Timwi: Exactly.